# iOS pong development, timer won't stop

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, timer

I'm creating a simple pong game..
right now i wanted to set a timer which will stop after i loose and save the value to high score possibly, but even though i managed to set up the timer and set him on, it seem to not want to stop.

i was implementing it using this tutorial:
http://www.apptite.be/tutorial_ios_stopwatch.php

Right now my code looks like this:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (StavHry == StavHryPozastaven) {
        TapToBegin.hidden = YES;
        StavHry = StavHryAktivni;
    } else if (StavHry == StavHryAktivni) {
        [self touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
    }
    startDate = [NSDate date];

    stopWatchTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/10.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateTimer)userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
} 

- (void)updateTimer
{
    static NSInteger counter = 0;
    StopWatchLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Counter: %i", counter++];

    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [currentDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];
    NSDate *timerDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeInterval];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss.SSS"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0.0]];
    NSString *timeString=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:timerDate];
    StopWatchLabel.text = timeString;
}
```

i set on the timer when i tap on TapToBegin label..
but when i loose or win the timer just keeps running even though i used invalidate in the function before setting off a new game.. (when i start a new game it resets)

```
-(void)reset:(BOOL) novahra { //funkce reset
    self.StavHry = StavHryPozastaven;
    mic.center = self.view.center;
    if(novahra) {
        if(skore_hrac_hodnota < skore_pc_hodnota){
            TapToBegin.text = @"Protivnik Vyhrál, smůla!";
            [stopWatchTimer invalidate];
        } else {
            TapToBegin.text = @"Vyhráls! Gratulujem!";
            [stopWatchTimer invalidate];
        }
        skore_hrac_hodnota = 0;
        skore_pc_hodnota = 0;
    } else {
        self.StavHry = StavHryAktivni;
        //TapToBegin.text = @"Pokračuj!";
    }

    skore_hrac.text  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", skore_hrac_hodnota];
    skore_pc.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", skore_pc_hodnota];
}
```

i know that the tutorial shows more lines of code for it's stop action, but i tried more options i gave it everything it has, but i think this is the only line which stops the timer so it should work. but it doesn't.

please help, i have a due on monday to finish this, so I'm freaking out a little.

Comment: A timer will only stop when you call `invalidate` on it - like you do in `reset:`. Do you call `invalidate` on the timer when you win or lose?

Comment: well i think i do.. at least that what appears to me in the code i posted here `if(skore_hrac_hodnota < skore_pc_hodnota){[stopWatchTimer invlidate]}else{...` that should be it

Comment: +1 for making Pong to learn game coding instead of an RPG or some other uber project with no chance of finishing.

Comment: thanks.. but now i need to finish it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens if `touchesBegan:` is called more than once and `reset:` is not called in between? if it can happen you probably leak a timer that will continue to call your `updateTimer` method.

Im a bit surprised if the code you posted works as the timer method should take an argument. That is change your timer selector to `@selector(updateTimer:)` and then change to the method to `- (void)updateTimer:(NSTimer *)timer`.

Comment: i don't think touchesBegan can be called more than once without calling reset: in-between.. (Im not sure though I'm a n00b), but it's a pong game when the points are shot into one of the sides the reset: function is called, i don't know how could be the touchesBegan function called more than once one after another.

Comment: anyway.. i did what you said.. thanks.. but still need to stop the timer.

Comment: Add `NSLog` or breakpoints when you create and invalidate the timer, then you will see if they match up.

Comment: not sure.. what am i looking for.. I am a beginner and still don't know what everything does (i do know what a breakpoint is though but what am i looking for in the debugger output?)

Comment: Add `NSLog(@"create stopWatchTimer=%@", stopWatchTimer);` after you create it an then in reset  `NSLog(@"invalidate stopWatchTimer=%@", stopWatchTimer);` and see if you create/invalidate the same timer instance. Note also that you should release the timer, invalidate only stops it.

Comment: oh yes now i see it.. I do create and invalidate the same instance: `2012-01-10 17:09:47.403 Pongify[62603:f803] create stopWatchTimer=<__NSCFTimer: 0x6e883b0>
2012-01-10 17:09:48.475 Pongify[62603:f803] invalidate stopWatchTimer=<__NSCFTimer: 0x6e883b0>`
isn't releasing now "automatic" i had been releasing everything previously but since Xcode 4 it always shows me some errors and i was reading about it and came to a conclusion that now it somehow doesn't need releases.

Comment: now as i keep playing the game i see it sometimes creates another timer or something and eve though it invalidates one timer it seems like there is another which was created at the same time..

it could be something with the releases but i can't use `[stopWatchTimer release];` at least the help won't let me - release is over crossed in the help popup menu.

Comment: Ok `touchesBegan` is definitely called more than once before `reset:` function and tends to create me like 10timers (actually a think it's one for every loop).. so only one is invalidated when i actually get to the reset function..

so what to do with this? how to prevent it?

Comment: If you see that another timer is created during game play i guess that you trigger touch even again somehow. Maybe you should disable the reset button of just return if the timer has already been assigned `if(stopWatchTimer) return` then you probably need to assign it to `nil` in reset.

Comment: If you compile with modern SDK and have enabled ARC you will not need to release stuff.

Comment: i don't have any reset button.. or well i have a touch to begin label which when i tap it starts the game, when i lose or win by shooting a number of points into an opponent or otherwise it shows the label with a different text when i tap the text it calls the reset a starts the game from dot.

but i need to prevent the timer before creating more timers because it happens during the game.

im not really sure what are you trying to tell me.

Comment: ok wait.. it creates the timer for every touch i make.. so if i just hold the paddle of the pong it won't create any timers.. so i think i might need to move the timer to different part of the code, but i can't move it to viewDidLoad because it would start immediately so i think touchesBegan should be right.

Comment: The idea is that the game should start when a user touches the screen?  if so i think you could check so that you only create a timer if it currently is nil.

Comment: i solved it... yeah that was basically the idea.. i even already had written an if which checks if the game is running so what i needed to do is insert the timer into that if instead of putting it somewhere else in the touchesBegan method.

Comment: it was so simple after all :)

Anyway thanks for your help, you really enlightened me on this area more than you think probably..

Comment: Sounds good :) welcome to stackoverflow btw and good luck with the game!